# How to get the human readable 2 digits milliseconds?

Tags: javascript

The following is the formula to get day:hours:minutes:seconds. I would like to get the two digits millisecond.

```
        var distance = countDownDate - now;

        // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
        var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
```

Comment: multiple seconds by 1000 since 1 sec =1000ms

Comment: I highly recommend using the very powerful [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) when doing any work with js dates.

Comment: I guess `countDownDate` and `now` are obtained via `Date` object. In this case you can't get (non-empty) milliseconds as `Date` interface has no such option. You have to use [`performance.now`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now) instead.

Comment: var mseconds  = seconds*1000; will do the job if i am right,for first two digits you can use mseconds.substr(0,2)

Comment: 'I would like to get the two digits millisecond.' what does this conveys to you @Charlie

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
var distance = countDownDate - now;

    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    var msecs = Math.floor((distance % 1000) / 10);
```